# JavaScript constructor parameter types

Tags: javascript, constructor, types

I have a JavaScript class representing a car, which is constructed using two parameters, which represent the make and model of the car:

```
function Car(make, model) {
     this.getMake = function( ) { return make; }
     this.getModel = function( ) { return model; }
}
```

Is there a way to verify that the make and model supplied to the constructor are strings? For example, I want the user to be able to say,

```
myCar = new Car("Honda", "Civic");
```

But I don't want the user to be able to say,

```
myCar = new Car(4, 5.5);
```

Comment: Don't forget to declare to your variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function Car(make, model) {
    if (typeof make !== 'string' || typeof model !== 'string') {
        throw new Error('Strings expected... blah');
    }
    this.getMake = function( ) { return make; };
    this.getModel = function( ) { return model; };
}
```

Or, just convert whatever you get to its string representation:

```
function Car(make, model) {
    make = String(make);
    model = String(model);
    this.getMake = function( ) { return make; };
    this.getModel = function( ) { return model; };
}
```

Comment: It's usually better to use `String(<smth>)` instead of `<smth>.toString()`, since there's really no guarantee that an object has `toString` and that its `toString` is callable. I would also suggest to terminate function expressions with semicolons — to avoid any nasty behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the typeof operator. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/typeof_Operator