# javascript: different constructors for same type of object

Tags: javascript, multiple-constructors

is it possible to have more than one constructors for a class in javascript?
i.e. one with zero parameters, one with one, one with two, etc...

if so, how?

thanks!

Comment: What you want shall be called "polymorphic function-constructor". look on http://www.highdots.com/forums/javascript/multiple-constructors-allowed-javascript-198415.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript pattern for multiple constructors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220721/javascript-pattern-for-multiple-constructors)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, Javascript does not support function overloading.

However, inside every function you have access to an [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments), which holds all the arguments supplied to the function, declared or not. You can simply look at it and decide what exactly you want to do in your constructor.

Bad, unrefined example:

```
function Foo() {

    function singleParamConstructor(foo) {
        ...
    }
    function twoParamConstructor(foo, bar) {
        ...
    }

    switch (arguments.length) {
        case 1 :
            singleParamConstructor(arguments[0]);
            break;
        case 2 :
            twoParamConstructor(arguments[0], arguments[1]);
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way apart from this one?

Comment: Well, *no*, Javascript does not support *function overloading*. There are probably innumerable design patterns with which you can avoid getting into a situation in which you think you need function overloading to begin with though.

Answer (score 1):

this might help: [JavaScript constructor parameter types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548953/javascript-constructor-parameter-types)